# Python append behaviour odd?

Tags: python, list

I've encountered what I think is odd behaviour for the `append()` function, and I've managed to duplicate it in the following simplified code:

```
plugh1 = []
plugh2 = []
n = 0
while n <= 4:
    plugh1.append(n)
    plugh2.append(plugh1)
    n = n+1
print plugh1
print plugh2
```

I would expect this code to result in:

```
plugh1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
plugh2 = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, ], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

but the actual result is:

```
plugh1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
plugh2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

As the loop runs, each time all array elements are replaced with the value of plugh1.

There is a similar question on SO but the solution seems related to nesting functions and defining a variable outside of those calls.  This is much simpler I think. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
plugh2.append(plugh1)
```

you are actually appending a reference to the first list, not the list as it currently is. Therefore the next time you do

```
plugh1.append(n)
```

you are changing the contents inside plugh2, as well.

You could copy the list like so, so that it doesn't change afterwards.

```
plugh2.append(plugh1[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this occurs is that you are not copying the list itself, but only the reference to the list. Try running:

```
print(pligh2[0] is pligh2[1])
#: True
```

Each element in the list "is" every other element because they are all the same objects.

If you want to copy this lists themselves, try:

```
plugh2.append(plugh1[:])
# or
plugh2.append(plugh1.copy())
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
plugh2.append(plugh1)
```

Appends a reference to `plugh1`, not a copy.  This means future updates are reflected in `plugh2`.  If you need a copy, see here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Could also just do `plugh2.append(plugh1[:])`

Comment: excellent.  Thanks for helping the newb.  Cheers